# Scope issues concerning conditional assignment for an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

I'm trying to deal with a number of different cases in my code dependent on attributes pulled from the HTTPRequest object. The thing is, different data gets pulled to fill the ArrayList dependent on the Request stuff, but the format is the same.

```
if (request.getAttribute("timePeriod").equals(null)) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>> HM = Test.getGlobalChallenge();
}
else {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>> HM = Test.getGlobalChallengeByMonth(Test);
}
```

If I don't initialize it before assignment, the code (in a JSP) says - of course - that it can't resolve the HM object.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>> HM = new ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>>();
if (request.getAttribute("timePeriod").equals(null)) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>> HM = Test.getGlobalChallenge();
}
else {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>> HM = Test.getGlobalChallengeByMonth(Test);
}
```

But if I initialize it, it complains about duplicate local variables. How can I set this to initialize/assign differently based on different situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was back before I knew much about variable scope and instantiation. I had two issues.

```
if (request.getAttribute("timePeriod").equals(null)) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>> HM = Test.getGlobalChallenge();
}
else {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>> HM = Test.getGlobalChallengeByMonth(Test);
}
```

Here, the variables only existed inside their respective cases; referencing them outside of this context failed, of course, because they didn't exist in a broader scope.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>> HM = new ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>>();
if (request.getAttribute("timePeriod").equals(null)) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>> HM = Test.getGlobalChallenge();
}
else {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>> HM = Test.getGlobalChallengeByMonth(Test);
}
```

And this one failed because I was trying to inadvertently instantiate a second HM value inside the if/else blocks, which conflicted with the first.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>> HM = new ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>>();
if (request.getAttribute("timePeriod").equals(null)) {
    HM = Test.getGlobalChallenge();
}
else {
    HM = Test.getGlobalChallengeByMonth(Test);
}
```

The correct way was to instantiate the variable in the broader scope, and reference it in the smaller scope - without reinitializing it.

Answer (score 5):

Don't declare the ArrayList again inside the if blocks.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>> HM;
if ((request.getAttribute("timePeriod") == null) {
    HM = Test.getGlobalChallenge();
}
else {
    HM = Test.getGlobalChallengeByMonth(Test);
}
```

Comment: Ah, okay. For some reason I thought that initializing it left room for it to be filled later - probably better to just leave it uninitialized. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>> HM;
if ((request.getAttribute("timePeriod") == null) {
    HM = Test.getGlobalChallenge();
}
else {
    HM = Test.getGlobalChallengeByMonth(Test);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot redeclare the variable. see below

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>> HM = new ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>>();
if ((request.getAttribute("timePeriod") == null) {
    HM = Test.getGlobalChallenge();
}
else {
    HM = Test.getGlobalChallengeByMonth(Test);
}
```

Comment: Unless getGlobalChallange throws an exception then HM is null.  What if HM cannot be nul when returned?...  without knowing the full scope then it is best to instantiate the array and allow the programmer to determine if it is ok to return null.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `HM` and initialize it to `null` outside your if/else and just use it inside your if/else like below:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<MyWeirdObject>> HM=null;
    if ((request.getAttribute("timePeriod") == null) {
       HM = Test.getGlobalChallenge();
    }
    else {
     HM = Test.getGlobalChallengeByMonth(Test);
    }
```